# Why does assigning `'initial'` for the `display` value not work for list items?

Tags: javascript, html

In order to toggle elements between displayed state and hidden state, I created a function that takes an object and a boolean, and assigns either `'none'` or `'initial'` for the `display` property of the given object depending on the boolean value.

This seemed to work for most elements like `<div>`, but for `<li>` items, assigning `'initial'` seems to erase the bullet, and it seems that particularly `'list-item'` (or `'grid'`) has to be assigned.

Why does `'initial'` not work for `<li>`, and how can I switch the objects between displayed and hidden states without having to mention the particular object type? I do not want to mention particular values in this function like `'block'`, `'inline'`, depending on the type of the object.

Comment: Just setting it to an empty string worked well for me.

Comment: @Bergi That seems so. And perhaps that is because it's invalid value, and will be ignored by the browser. Does this, then, mean that any invalid value will work?

Comment: `initial` is valid, but it doesn't mean what you think it means. :) Does `list-item` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
element.style.display = "";
```

which means removing the inline style from the element.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work. I think I can also go with something like `null`.

Comment: Yeah, `null` works as well, other falsy values like `undefined`, `false` or `0` don't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does assigning `'initial'` for the `display` value not work for
>   list items?

There's nothing special about list items over here. If you apply `display:initial` to **any element** be it a `<li>` a `<div>` or anything else - the result will be equivalent to applying `display:inline` to that element because the **initial value of the CSS display property** is `inline`

From [MDN on the display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> Initial value:    inline

Take a look at [this codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/YwxYva) - Notice that if you hover over the content, all the `<div>` elements 'shrink' and become 'inline' even though they are being set with `display:initial`

> How can I switch the objects between displayed and hidden states
>   without having to mention the particular object type?

You could simply toggle a class which when added - sets that element with `display:none`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of `'initial'`.